# JavaFXPorts built apk automatically deleted

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, apk, javafxports

When I build an apk with JavaFXPorts using `gradle android`, I find the apk under `build\javafxports\android\MyApplication.apk`. However, when I run any other gradle task after that, the apk is automatically and instantly getting *DELETED*.

I am clueless as to why this happens, since I'm not issuing a clean or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run a task from the jfxmobile plugin, the Android, iOS and embedded extensions are added.

According to [this](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/72d6b669982d88bd33a60a7d2a720ecad0d759a6/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/android/AndroidExtension.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#AndroidExtension.groovy-54), the folders `javafxports/android` and `javafxports/tmp/android` are deleted and created all over again. That means that any content there (your apk) will be removed.

If you think this is a bug, you can file an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues?status=new&status=open).

You can also try to fix it, for instance by adding a task to do a backup of your apk every time you create it.

Something like this, added to the `build.gradle` file of your project, should work:

```
[android, androidInstall].each {task -> task.doLast() { 
        copy {
            from 'build/javafxports/android'
            into "build/apk"
        }
    }
}
```